# Which of the Konica I, II, III, S, SII, SIIII rangefinder variants have a lifesize (1:1) finder?

Tags: film, rangefinder, konica

I wonder whether anyone knows some historic fact about the konica rangefinder models that predate the auto S sites. As far as I know, the lifesize finder was introduced in the IIIa and IIIm models. Was it available after these models in the S series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can say that the SII does not have a lifesize finder as I have one. Also, I looked up the Konica S manual, and it states that thew viewfinder has 0.65 magnification. I believe this leaves the IIIa, and IIIm series as the only series with a 1:1 finder. The III does not have a 1:1 finder.

http://www.cameramanuals.org/konica/konica_s.pdf

Answer (score 1):

From
http://www.rangefinderforum.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-43028.html

I quote:

> The Konica III, III A and III M
>   (http://www.dantestella.com/technical/koni3.html) were superb fixed
>   lens RF cameras with bright 1:1 viewfinders.

See the linked thread for a nice discussion about cameras with 1:1 viewfinders.